# scala pass partial value to collect body

Tags: scala

I have a long call query which I want to map and filter the results by it and pass the call result to the collect body so I will be able to use it without call to it again .

```
def veryLongFoo(i:Int):Option[Int] 

val myList = (1 to 100).toList
myList.collect{ case x if veryLongFoo(x).isDefined =>    
  val y = veryLongFoo(x).get // I want to avoid calling veryLongFoo(x) again
  y
}
```

is there elegant solution for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
(1 to 100).flatMap(veryLongFoo)
```

`veryLongFoo` is computed for each `Int` and returns an `Option[Int]`. This `Option[Int]` is then converted into a `Traversable` (through an implicit `CanBuildFrom`) containing 0 element if it is a `None` or only 1 element if it is a `Some`. All those obtained `Traversable` are then concatenated together thanks to the `flatMap` operation.

Comment: Definitely the correct answer, possibly a little more explanation to the user to why it works?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly perverse answer, use an [extractor](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html):

```
def veryLongFoo(i:Int): Option[Int] = ???

object Wrap {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Int] = veryLongFoo(x)
}

val myList = (1 to 100).toList
myList.collect {
  case Wrap(x) => x // presumably do something else with x...
}
```

But don't actually do this, use `flatMap` instead!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to return not an Option but a Future

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def veryLongFoo(i:Int):Future[Int]

val myList = (1 to 100).toList
myList.collect{ case x =>
    Await.result(veryLongFoo(x), 1 minute) // I want to avoid calling veryLongFoo(x) again
}
```

and inside the `veryLongFoo` you need to maintain some `Map[Int, Future[Int]` hence if the future is not there - you need to start it and put into the map. Once the Future completes - it will simply return the result. If it is still pending computation - then Await will wait until it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would map it first, and then collect:

```
def veryLongFoo(i:Int):Option[Int]

val myList = (1 to 100).toList

myList.map(veryLongFoo)
    .collect {
      case Some(result) => result
    }
```